# boost file system issue in c++ windows universal application

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

I am working with c++/winrt. I have to use boost filesytem. But looks like the keyword "generic" in boost and winrt are conflicting. Is there any way to get rid if it? Or we can't use boost on winrt?

```
error C2059: syntax error: 'generic'
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

Comment: What's the relevance of the [tag:c++-cli] tag? I'm not aware of any way to use C++/CLI in a native UWP application.

Comment: its not relevant . Removed the tag. Thanks